# Drawing a clinical study subjects flow chart directly in R within a Jupyter notebook

Tags: r, jupyter

I'm using R (3.x) within Jupyter to perform some statistical analysis of a clinical study.

The flow of subjects is pretty complex and I would like to draw the Patient flow chart directly in my notebook. Like this one :

[image]

Why ? 
To make sure the subjects count is consistent with the code, and not having to maintain sync between the R code and this figure.

I've tried DiagrammeR (won't install for some reason), RGrahpviz (too complex and doesn't meet the requirements).

A perfect solution might come from [mermaid](https://mermaidjs.github.io/) but I couldn't find a way to have it integrated with my Jupyter/R notebooks.

I'm *not* using a `python` Jupyter notebook but a `R` notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mentioned that DiagrammeR won't install, but I would still provide one solution using DiagrammeR anyway--in case you have solved the installation issue. Suppose after you have made the graph using DimagrammeR and obtained a grViz object named myGraph. To display it under jupyter notebook, I use the following

```
require('DiagrammeR')
require('DiagrammeRsvg') #export grViz objects to svg
require('IRdisplay')
mySVG<-export_svg(myGraph)
display_svg(data=mySVG)
```